# Problems with numpy polyfit

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

For some reason, my polyfit is way way off, and I cannot figure out why that is. My scatter plot seems normal.

[Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iqE5.png)

[PolyFit Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsA98.png)

How can I fix this? here is my code:

```
def plot(data, x_axis, y_axis, title):
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]

    ## Plot data
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
    plt.scatter(x, y)

    idx = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y)
    plt.plot(np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x[idx], y[idx], 3)))

    ## Format graph
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(3))       
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

    ## Define labels
    plt.xlabel(x_axis)
    plt.ylabel(y_axis)
    plt.title(title)

    ## Graph data
    plt.show()
```

If I need to link my data, then I can. There's too much of it to post here.

Inspecting

```
print(x[idx])
print(y[idx])
```

Shows the correct values and nothing seems off.

[x[idx] and y[idx] plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elSBk.png)

EDIT:
I have figured out my solution. I was not using polyfit correctly.

```
    idx = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y)
    avgTrend = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x[idx], y[idx], 3))
    plt.plot(x, avgTrend(x), color='red')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fLF1.png)

Comment: I feel like I should remove the data points from 1983 since they do appear to be outliers, but I would rather not remove them at this moment. I haven't done much research, so there may have some big event in 1983.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the degree of the polynomial. For so many data points it may be simply impossible to fit a good degree 3 polynomial. You could try a higher degree (unlikely to work in the way you want it) or you can try a spline function.

For example you could try the csaps package that implements smoothing splines and that I can recommend.

Hope this helps

Comment: I ended up getting it to work. I think the problem was, I wasn't passing in the dates, so that was why trend line wasn't aligning properly with my scatter plot. I uploaded my solution at the bottom with a picture of the graph.